# Why "lsof -wni tcp:3000"

Tags: lsof

When I encounter "a server is already running" I use below command to solve this issue

```
lsof -wni tcp:3000" 
kill -9 pid
```

I undertand `lsof`, but don't understand why `"-wni"`, **does anybody know what "-wni" stands for?**

Also I could use `lsof -i tcp:3000`, but **what is the difference between lsof -i tcp:3000 and lsof -wni tcp:3000?**

Thanks.

Comment: `lsof -wni tcp:3000` is a shortcut for `lsof -w -n -i tcp:3000`. Find an lsof documentation to find out the meaning of the options w, n, and i. Maybe ther is a documentation on your system, try `info lsof` or `man lsof`.

Comment: Thanks Miracle, I understand now. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run `man lsof` to find out those flags.

-w     Enables (+) or disables (-) the suppression of warning messages.

-n       inhibits  the  conversion of network numbers to host names for network files.  Inhibiting conversion may make lsof run faster.
                It is also useful when host name lookup is not working properly.

-i [i]   selects the listing of files any of whose Internet address matches the address specified in i.  If no  address  is  specified,
                this option selects the listing of all Internet and x.25 (HP-UX) network files.

Comment: thank you very much Edmund Lee, I understand now. Really appreciate.